# Number of pairwise disjoint subsets of a set R, where the total cardinality of the pairwise subsets is less than or equal to some k < |R|

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm not a mathematician and so I am not sure if my question is worded right. I am a software engineer who just started doing a PhD and so there is a lot of theoretical computer-science stuff that involves a lot of math.

Here's the essence of what I am doing. I have a set $R = \{r_1, \dotso, r_n\}$. I am defining an $S = \langle R_1, R_2 \rangle$ such that $R_1 \subset R$, $R_2 \subset R$, $R_1 \cap R_2 = \varnothing$, $|R_1| \le k_1$ , $|R_2| \le k_2$ and $k_1 + k_2 < |R|$.

I am describing a set of all such $S$ values. What would the cardinality of this set be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For fixed $|R_1| = j_1$ and $|R_2| = j_2$, the number of choices $\langle R_1, R_2 \rangle$ is $\dfrac{n!}{j_1! j_2! (n - j_1 - j_2)!}$.  You then want to sum
this for $j_1 = 0 \ldots k_1$, $j_2 = 0 \ldots k_2$.  I don't know if there is a closed form for the double sum.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain how you arrived at this solution?

Comment: Not that I don't doubt it is correct, it's just so I understand how you arrived at it.

Comment: @VivinPaliath The expression he gave is the [multinomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial) ${n\choose j_1,j_2,n-j_1-j_2}$ which gives the number of ways to partition a set of size $n$ into three subsets of sizes $j_1$, $j_2$, $n-j_1-j_2$ respectively (in this case these would be $R_1$, $R_2$ and $R\setminus(R_1\cup R_2)$).